# Deleting a non-existed node in linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, segmentation-fault

**Problem Description:**

I have made a class Node with an int key, int del and Node* next. When I try to delete nodes that doesn't exist in the list it returns with a segmentation fault.

**Context:**

```cpp
void Node::Del(int k) // here k is the key given to search
  {
    Node *curr = head; // ptr that traverses the list
    Node *temp = NULL; // the pointer trails behind curr to store value of node one position behind curr

    while (curr->key != k && curr != NULL)
    {
        temp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    if (curr == NULL) // if key not found (not working properly)
    {
        return;
    }

    else if (curr == head) // if head contains the key
    {
        head = curr->next;
        delete curr;
        return;
    }

    else if (curr->key == k) // if key exists in the node
    {
        temp->next = curr->next;
        delete curr;
    }
}
```

**Solution that did not work**

I have a condition `if( curr == NULL ){ return;}` meaning if it is the last node in list then finish work,  but instead it It returns segmentation fault.

Comment: If you step through with a Debugger you'll notice it crashes on `while (curr->key != k && curr != NULL)`, because you check curr->key (dereferencing the pointer) before checking if curr is NULL. Just reverse the order of the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition

```
curr->key != k && curr != NULL
```

cannot possibly work. Not only for linked lists, but not in any context. Why? Because if curt == NULL then the first part of the condition curt->key will already crash. You need to do two things:

1. Exchange the left and right hand side of the &&.
2. Much more important: Find out what compiler settings would give you a warning for your code, and always compile with these settings. My compiler wouldn’t have allowed me to build and run this code because of the obvious bug.